# Get automatically determined value of FlowDocument.PageWidth property

Tags: c#, wpf, width, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a WPF `RichTextBox` control, and I set the value of the  `RichTextBox.Document.PageWidth` property to `double.NaN` in order to have the value be determined automatically.

Now I'd like to get the automatically determined value, but I cannot do so by reading the value of the property, as it returns `double.NaN`.

**EDIT**

I try getting the value of `RichTextBox.DesiredSize` in the `OnMyPropertyChanged` method of the property that can be set to auto (with a value of `double.NaN`):

```
if (!double.IsNaN(MyProperty)) richTextBox.Width = MyProperty;
else richTextBox.Width = richTextBox.DesiredWidth;
```

However, `DesiredSize` returns 0 on both axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `TextBlock` control (without necessarily adding it to any parent control), set the text value you need to get the width of, and also the font properties (`FontFamily`, `FontStyle`, `FontWeight`, `FontStretch` and `FontSize`), then call the `Measure` method on the control, so that it determines the value of its `DesiredSize` property, which you can read then.

Answer (score 2):

It's by design... RichTextBox was meant to exist in a fixed width views. A walkaround that should work - put it into a border, and bind the width of the rich text box to the ActualWidth of the border.

Cheers.

Comment: Not bad idea, but if I set any Width property to auto, the width is adjusted so that the right bound of the control is at the rigth bound of its containing control. Thus, no Width-like property adjusts its value based on the width of the text in a Rich text box. It does so in a regular text box or text block, but not on a rich text box.

Anyway, I figured out a rude solution but it works fine, I posted it as an answer.